# Full Outer Join Query receiving error

Tags: mysql, sql, full-outer-join

Have a simple mysql query that is recieving an error message.

here is the query:

```
$query_parts = "SELECT I.sku, I.orderID, P.sku, P.description FROM inventory I FULL OUTER JOIN parts P ON I.sku = P.sku WHERE I.orderID = $orderID";
```

here is the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FULL OUTER JOIN parts P ON I.sku = P.sku WHERE I.orderID = 4881166' at line 1
```

please help, to me, it looks pretty straight forward.

Comment: I don't think MySQL has implemented FULL OUTER JOIN.

Comment: I'm pretty sure MySQL still doesn't support the [FULL OUTER JOIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql) syntax.